# Using Office.js or Office Scripts outside of Excel or Excel Add-in

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

I am trying to Get the Value of the Active cell in Excel

I was able to get the Value by writing a simple Excel Add-in.

I was also able to do the same using Office-Scripts

Office-Script:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get the current active cell in the workbook.
    let cell = workbook.getActiveCell();

    // Log that cell's value.
    console.log(`The current cell's value is ${cell.getValue()}`);
}
```

[Office-Script in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN3dM.png)

Similar code was used for Add-In:
Used stock code (example code) which did the same job

Home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.5.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/MessageBanner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- To enable offline debugging using a local reference to Office.js, use: -->
    <!-- <script src="../Scripts/Office/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  -->
    <!-- <script src="../Scripts/Office/1/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  -->

    <script src="Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../Content/Button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../Content/MessageBanner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <!-- For the Office UI Fabric Core, go to https://aka.ms/office-ui-fabric to learn more. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/9.6.0/css/fabric.min.css">

    <!-- To enable the offline use of Office UI Fabric Core, use: -->
    <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/fabric.min.css" -->


    <!-- Office UI Fabric JS and it's components are no longer actively supported. Please see https://aka.ms/PnP-OfficeFabricReact for recommended Patterns and Practices -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.components.min.css"> -->

</head>
<body class="ms-Fabric" dir="ltr">
    <div id="content-main">
        <div class="padding">
            <br />
            <div class="ms-font-xxl ms-fontColor-themeDarkAlt ms-fontWeight-semilight">Welcome</div>
            <p class="ms-font-m-plus">This example will read the current document selection.</p>

            <button class="Button Button--primary" id="get-data-from-selection">
                <span class="Button-icon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--plus"></i></span>
                <span class="Button-label">Get data from selection</span>
                <span class="Button-description">Gets the selected data and displays it.</span>
            </button>
            <br /><br /><br />
            <div class="ms-font-m"><a target="_blank" class="ms-Link ms-Link--hero" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276813">Find more samples online...</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Component used for displaying notifications -->
    <div class="MessageBanner" style="position:absolute;bottom: 0;">
        <div class="MessageBanner-content">
            <div class="MessageBanner-text">
                <div class="MessageBanner-clipper">
                    <div class="ms-font-m-plus ms-fontWeight-semibold" id="notificationHeader"></div>
                    <div class="ms-font-m ms-fontWeight-semilight" id="notificationBody"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="MessageBanner-expand" style="display:none"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--chevronsDown"></i> </button>
            <div class="MessageBanner-action"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="MessageBanner-close"> <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChromeClose"></i> </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Home.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var messageBanner;

    // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        console.log("Inside Initialization")
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var element = document.querySelector('.MessageBanner');
            messageBanner = new components.MessageBanner(element);
            messageBanner.hideBanner();

            $('#get-data-from-selection').click(getDataFromSelection);
        });
        console.log("done Initialization")
    };

    // Reads data from current document selection and displays a notification
    function getDataFromSelection() {
        if (Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync) {
            Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text,
                function (result) {
                    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                        showNotification('The selected text is:', '"' + result.value + '"');
                    } else {
                        showNotification('Error:', result.error.message);
                    }
                }
            );
        } else {
            app.showNotification('Error:', 'Reading selection data is not supported by this host application.');
        }
    }
    
    // Helper function for displaying notifications
    function showNotification(header, content) {
        $("#notificationHeader").text(header);
        $("#notificationBody").text(content);
        messageBanner.showBanner();
        messageBanner.toggleExpansion();
    }
})();
```

Now, I am trying to run this script from outside of Excel, similar to VBScript where I can run the script independently outside Excel and get the active workbook, active cell and corresponding value.

I tried running the JS code from outside of excel
I am getting this error:

```
Warning: Office.js is loaded outside of Office client
office.js:46 The add-in is not hosted in plain browser top window.
Ewa.js:1 SendShuttingDownRequest: https://excel.officeapps.live.com/x/RemoteUls.ashx?officeserverversion=16.0.14206.35904&waccluster=GSH7; requestApi: f
```

[Office.js loaded outside of Office Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKU5h.png)

Here I'm using Excel in Sharepoint on a browser
I am injecting the JS code to the webpage (Excel Sharepoint page),
JS code calls `Office.initialize` and `getDataFromSelection()`(mentioned above) also loaded `"https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"` and tried to get the active cell value of Excel.

But as soon I call Initialize, Excel Sharepoint page will go blank cause of the shutdown (probably cause of this `SendShuttingDownRequest`).

In my current use case, I would have to use an external script to get data from Excel Sharepoint page, and also I will not be able to use Power Automate to run the scripts.

1. Am I doing something wrong in the way of using the JS API?
2. Is there a way to use JS APIs to get data out of Excel similar to VB Script?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Office.js outside of the context of an add-in. It needs to get information from the Excel host in order to initialize.

Comment: Got it, Any suggestion on how to solve this problem
Basically I want to get Data (active cell, active table etc) out of Excel Sharepoint Page to my browser extension